# How can i automate buttons between two div classes

Tags: selenium, uibutton, automation

My html code looks like this

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text">Delete</span>
</button>
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
</button>
</div>
```

I need to click on delete button here using my webdriver scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using selenium webdriver and xpath is an option. Use `xpath` and text based search

`//span[.='Delete']`

Comment: Hi thanks for solution it worked fine when i am running single test,but when i am running same testcase in suite it throws "Element is currently not visisble" exception

Comment: That might be a wait issue. Use implicit wait. Let me know which language you are using. Will try to help